# How to specify pnpm as the "Package manager" in IntelliJ > Prefs > Languages & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM?

Tags: intellij-idea, package-managers, pnpm

I have *pnpm* installed on my Mac (MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)). I verify that fact by running `which pnpm` and `pnpm --version` in Terminal.app, where both succeed.

When I click the *Package manager* pop-up menu, I get menu items for *npm*, *yarn*, and *pnpm*. But when I choose *pnpm*, I get an error saying "Not found".

How can I get IntelliJ to "find" my *pnpm* installation?

[image]

When I click the `+` icon for the list of package managers, I get a list which I can narrow to *pnpm*, but the item in the list has blank fields.

Comment: Is it pnpm > 16.14.3? Seems similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52365

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov Yes, that seems to be it. My *pnpm* is indeed located in the `Library` folder. If you want to make an Answer of your Comment, I will accept it to mark this page as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*pnpm* version greater than 16.14.3 changed its default location. The new location for macOS is `~/Library/pnpm`.

That is why IntelliJ cannot detect it. Here is the bug on JetBrains issue tracker:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52365

The only workaround seems to be to downgrade, as defining pnpm location manually is not working currently.